# Configuring devices in chroot-environment OpenBSD

Tags: python, cgi, chroot, openbsd, jail

I have been scratching my head for a while now and cannot find a way to make it work...

I want to run some cgi scripts (written in Python) on my OpenBSD server. Since the web-server on OpenBSD runs in a jail I recreated the whole folder structure (/bin /dev /usr /usr/local/lib etc. etc.) but I'm still getting '500 Server Internal Error' when I'm trying to import some Python modules that require access to /dev/urandom device.

I have created the device special files using mknod.

```
ls -la /dev/*random
ls -la /dev/{null,zero}
```

I got the following output

```
crw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   45,   3 Sep 13 11:09 /dev/arandom
crw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   45,   0 Jul 15 19:02 /dev/random
crw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   45,   1 Jul 15 19:02 /dev/srandom
crw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   45,   2 Jul 15 19:02 /dev/urandom
```

and

```
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    2,   2 Sep 16 01:30 /dev/null
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    2,  12 Jul 15 19:02 /dev/zero
```

So I executed the following commands in the /var/www/dev folder (OpenBSD web-server runs in chroot -u www /var/www)

```
mknod -m 666 null c 2 2
mknod -m 666 zero c 2 12
mknod -m 644 random 45 0
mknod -m 644 srandom 45 1
mknod -m 644 urandom 45 2
mknod -m 644 arandom 45 3
```

However, Python still reports that the

```
OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured '/dev/urandom'
```

The same code works fine in a non-chroot-ed environment.

```
import os
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
```

Any help would be truly appreciated!

Comment: This is almost certainly a system configuration issue—you didn't set up the jail right—rather than a Python one. You can test that very easily by just seeing what happens when you run, say, `head -c16 /dev/urandom` or `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16 count=1` from inside the jail. If you get the same error, go ask on SuperUser or ServerFault or  another general Unix or OpenBSD forum.

Comment: Thanks for this! dd command shows exactly the same result as Python. So it is definitely configuration issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On OpenBSD non-root (`/`) partitions are mounted with `nodev` option. Look at your `/etc/fstab`. For example:

```
$ mount | grep -F /var
/dev/wd0g on /var type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid)
```

Comment: Same thing for NetBSD.